# How can i use a base address to get a dynamic?

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, memory

So, I've been trying to get the value from a dynamic address for a while now and the results are this https://gyazo.com/82ef5920d01c4452840764111c60e046 When infact my Health value is 100,

This is what I've tried to do so far, I tried to read the Base address store it in a temp then read the temp+HealthOffset into temp again, then i would read the temp into an integer and try to print it. It doesn't work when i try to write to write to it either

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream >
#define base 0x0050f4f4

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DWORD healthoffset[] = { 0xF8 };
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "AssaultCube");
    DWORD iProc = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, 0);
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, iProc);
    DWORD temp;
    int storage;
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPCVOID)base, &temp, sizeof(temp), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPCVOID)(temp + healthoffset[1]),     &temp,   sizeof(temp), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPCVOID)temp, &storage, sizeof(int), 0);  
    cout << storage;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't 'Windows' in the tag be good?

Comment: yeah i'll fix it my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe healthoffset[1] must be healthoffset[0].

It is an Array of length 1 and you access the first element with index 0.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream >
#define base 0x0050f4f4

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DWORD healthoffset[] = { 0xF8 };
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "AssaultCube");
    DWORD iProc = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, 0);
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, iProc);

    DWORD temp;
    int storage;


    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPCVOID)base, &temp, sizeof(temp), 0);
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPCVOID)(temp + healthoffset), &storage, sizeof(storage), 0);
    cout << storage;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Woah thanks man I remember I used to go on your channel and learn to gamehack, I never thought I'd see you on here. You did a great thing for kids all across the globe!

Comment: @David Morales haha thanks, we're still going strong